# Hi, I am supposed to store a value x in a array pointed by the pointer at value z, which is calculated in another function. am I doing it right?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, hashtable, computer-science

```c
    // This function inserts an element into the hash table.
    // 1) First, hash the value of `x` using `hash_el` to get `z = h(x)`
    // 2) Then, if the array pointed to `ht[z]` is empty (element `[0]` = 0), insert `x` into element `[1]`
    //    in the array at `ht[z]`, and increase the element counter in element `[0]`
    // 3) If the array pointed to by `ht[z]` is not empty
    //    (e.g. element `[0]` != 0), you will have to reallocate more size in the array.
    // Arguments:
    // - ht: an array of pointers to integer arrays, where values will be stored
    // - x: a pointer to an integer x, where x is the value to be inserted into ht
    void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
        int *z = (int*) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
        hash_el(x, z, value); 
        if(ht[*z][0] == 0){
                ht[*z][1] = *x;
                ht[*z][0] = 1;
        }
        else if(ht[*z][0] != 0){
                int size = (sizeof(&ht[*z])/((sizeof(ht[*z][0]))));
                ht[*z] = (int*)realloc(ht[*z],(size + 1)*sizeof(int));
                for(int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++){
                        if(ht[*z][i] == 0){
                                ht[*z][i] = *x;
                                ht[*z][0] = 1;
                        }
                }
        }    
}
```

The description of the code is given above as comments. kindly let me know if I am making a mistake. `*z` is being called to initialize `z`, which later stores the value returned by the `has_el` function. Then I compare the 0 element of the array pointed by the value of `z`, if the element is zero, I aasign it the value of `x`, however, if it is not zero, I allocate more memory with the help of `realloc`, and then store the value of `x` at this new place.
This is how implemented my hashtable:

```c
const int value = HT_SIZE;

int main() {
    // Create your array of pointers to integer arrays (ht) of length HT_SIZE (= 29) here. This will be your hash table.
    int *ht[HT_SIZE]; // Add code below to create `ht`:
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < value ; j++ ) {
        ht[j] = (int*) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    }
```

I have edited my code for the size and *z thing:

```c
    void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
        int z;
        hash_el(x, &z, value);
        if(ht[z][0] == 0){
                ht[z][1] = *x;
                ht[z][0] = 1;
        }
        else if(ht[z][0] != 0){
                int size = ht[z][0];
                int new_size = size + 1;
                ht[z] = (int*)realloc(ht[z],(new_size)*sizeof(int));
                for(int i = 0; i < new_size; i++){
                        if(ht[z][i] == 0){
                                ht[z][i] = *x;
                                ht[z][0] = 1;
                                
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I have edited my code once again according to the suggestions but it still does not work.

```c
    void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
        int z;
        hash_el(x, &z, value);
        if(ht[z][0] == 0){
                ht[z][1] = *x;
                ht[z][0] = 1;
        }
        else if(ht[z][0] != 0){
                int size = ht[z][0];
                int new_size = size + 1;
                ht[z] = (int*)realloc(ht[z],(new_size)*sizeof(int));
                ht[z][size] = *x;
        }
}
```

I have changed the code according to the changes suggested by you, but it still seems to have an error.

```c
    void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
        int z;
        hash_el(x, &z, value);
        if(ht[z][0] == 0){
                ht[z][1] = *x; 
                ht[z][0] = 1;
        } 
        else {
                int size = ht[z][0];
                int new_size = size + 1;
                ht[z] = realloc(ht[z],(new_size)*sizeof(int));
                ht[z][size] = *x;
                ht[z][0] = new_size;
        }
}
```

By the way, my code for free is this:

```c
void free_ht(int *ht[]) {
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < value ; ++j ) {
        free(&ht[j]);
```

could the error in `insert_el` be because of this?

Comment: You'll need to describe how the hash table is implemented. Apparently as some manner of array of pointers? `ht[*z][1]` doesn't make much sense in that case. Are all items unique or otherwise how does it handle collisions?

Comment: this is how I implemented my hash table :const int value = HT_SIZE;

int main() {
    // Create your array of pointers to integer arrays (ht) of length HT_SIZE (= 29) here. This will be your hash table.
    int *ht[HT_SIZE]; // Add code below to create `ht`:
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < value ; j++ ) {
                ht[j] = (int*) calloc(2, sizeof(int));
            }

Comment: Your usage of `z` doesn't make much sense. You only need a pointer to allow `hash_el` returning a value. For this purpose you should use `int z;` and pass `&z` to `hash_el`

Comment: @Gerhardh can you please show that by making an edit in the code?

Comment: This will not work: `sizeof(&ht[*z])` You cannot get the size of an allocated memory. You need to keep track of the allocated size yourself. Besides that this expression will only yield the size of a pointer.

Comment: @HannanSandhu That still doesn't answer how it handles collisions, which must be known before you can implement the insert function.

Comment: @Gerhardh my parameters for the hash_el function are this: void hash_el(int *input, int *output, int value)

Comment: No, I will not change the code in the question accordingly. 1) This is not causing your issue but only some side note. 2) We are not supposed to change your code (besides formatting, typos etc.) to make your question a moving target. 3) What is unclear about replacing `*z` => `z` and `z` => `&z`?

Comment: @Lundin I am handling collisons with this second for loop used in insert_el function, which allocates new memory for another element to be stored.

Comment: @Gerhardh i think using z instead of *z would not give us a pointer, however in the parameter of the hash_el function we need a pointer to store the output

Comment: If you make `z` an `int`, which part of `&z` is not a pointer to `int`? You don't need to allocate memory just because you need a pointer. The address of a variable also servers as a pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh I have edited the size part following your reason, but it still does not run

Comment: @Gerhardh I am not allocating memory becuase i need a pointer, I am doing it to get space for another element to be stored in the array pointed by z

Comment: No, you don't allocate space for another element in the array pointer by `z`. You allocate memory for another element in the array pointed to by pointer `ht[*z]`. That is very different. You only allocate memory for 1 `int` for `z` and then use only that `int` and do not store the address stored in `z` anywhere, creating a memory leak.

Comment: @Gerhardh would " int size = (sizeof(&ht[*z])/((sizeof(ht[*z][0])))); " give me the size of the array pointed by z?

Comment: No, as I wrote, you cannot get the size of allocated memory. And as I already mentioned above, `z` does not point to an array at all. `ht[*z]` does. Keep your details precise. Don't mix up things. Don't get sloppy. But still, there is no way to get the size.

Comment: @Gerhardh I did not get this: No, you don't allocate space for another element in the array pointer by z. You allocate memory for another element in the array pointed to by pointer ht[*z]. That is very different. You only allocate memory for 1 int for z and then use only that int and do not store the address stored in z anywhere, creating a memory leak., can you please explain this a bit more, or can you point to the chnages that need to be made please ?

Comment: I know ht[*z] points to the array, so how can i get the size of the array pointed by ht[*z] ?

Comment: Again: YOU CANNOT DO THIS.

Comment: And regarding previous comment: Do you know difference between `ht[*z]` and `z`? You seem to mix them all the time in your comments.

Comment: Is `ht[z][0]` supposed to hold the number of elements in the allocated memory? Then you should assign `ht[z][0] = new_size;` instead of `ht[z][0] = 1;` after increasing the size

Comment: `if(ht[z][i] == 0){` What is this check supposed to do? Do you want to be able to store `0` values in your arrays? Also you must be aware that the new memory reserved by `realloc` is not initialized. As you already decided you need to increase the size, why not just assign directly to `ht[z][size] = *x;`?  (You know, `x` would't need to ba a pointer as yoz only store the value, not the address, do you?

Comment: @Gerhardh I have changed the size as you told, and I agree with what you explained about it, but can you please explain your last comment as I don't get the logic of ht[z][size] = *x, as wont we need to increase the size of the array first? Moreover, if ht[z][0] == 0, then the check is supposed to assign *x to ht[z][1], as initially we created every array to a pointer to be of size 2.

Comment: You *already have* increased the size. Why do you look for a place to insert new value? Just add at the new index.

Comment: @Gerhardh I cannot do that as my instructor wants me to reallocate using realloc in this situation

Comment: @Gerhardh I have edited my code once again, kindly give it a look.

Comment: That second update is rather close. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh I have edited my code again according to your updated answer, but still does not work.

Comment: You will have to be a bit more precise what "does not work" means.

Comment: my insert_el function does not work, when ever I run the code, I receive this : "Testing `hash_el`... success!
Your `insert_el` function has issues."

Comment: That is not a useful description. How do you call it? What do you insert? How do you test? Show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when I compile the code, it complies, but when I run it, then it produces the error described in my last comment.

Comment: By the way, is *x appropriate for storing the value of x in ht[z][1], may be it is producing the error?

Comment: As this evolves to a completely different issue, I suggest you create a new question. With a MCVE, with sample input, output and expected output. BTW: Your code does not contain any output like `"Testing hash_el... success! Your insert_el function has issues."` This means you are missing important parts here. If that message comes from some test framework at your class, you need to provide your own framework to call your function with suitable parameters.

Comment: `free(&ht[j]);` is clearly wrong. It must be `free(ht[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

You have various issues:

First, you do not store or return address assigned to `z`:

```c
    void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
        int *z = (int*) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
        hash_el(x, z, value); 
        if(ht[*z][0] == 0){
                ht[*z][1] = *x;
                ht[*z][0] = 1;
        }
        else if(ht[*z][0] != 0){
                int size = (sizeof(&ht[*z])/((sizeof(ht[*z][0]))));
                ht[*z] = (int*)realloc(ht[*z],(size + 1)*sizeof(int));
                for(int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++){
                        if(ht[*z][i] == 0){
                                ht[*z][i] = *x;
                                ht[*z][0] = 1;
                        }
                }
        }    
}
```

You also don't seem to need a pointer here at all. Use it like this:

```c
void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
    int z;
    hash_el(x, &z, value); 
    if (ht[z][0] == 0) {
        ht[z][1] = *x;
        ht[z][0] = 1;
    }
    else if (ht[z][0] != 0) {
        int size = (sizeof(&ht[z])/((sizeof(ht[z][0]))));
        ht[*z] = realloc(ht[z],(size + 1)*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
            if (ht[z][i] == 0) {
                ht[z][i] = *x;
                ht[z][0] = 1;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This leaves another problem:
In C it is not possible to determine the size of memory pointed to by a pointer.

```c
        int size = (sizeof(&ht[z])/((sizeof(ht[z][0]))));
```

This only works if you have an array. And that means an array that you define as a variable (local of global) but not some allocated memory.
It also does not work with array parameters in a function as they also decay to pointers.

Whatever you try, **it is not possible** to get the size just by looking at the address.

It is up to you to keep track of allocated memory.
You will have to store the size next to each pointer in your `ht` array.
Using a struct holding the address and the counter might be useful.

UPDATE:

With your updated code you are using `ht[z][0]` to store the size of the allocated memory. That is OK but your implementation is broken.

After increasing the memory you don't need to look for an entry to place the new value. It must be the ony you just added using `realloc`. If you search for `0` values you can never use your code to store `0` bytes as data value.
With the second update you are close but miss to update your size.

```c
void insert_el(int *ht[], int *x) {
    int z;
    hash_el(x, &z, value);
    if (ht[z][0] == 0) {
        ht[z][1] = *x;
        ht[z][0] = 1;
    }
    else{  // No need for an if (ht[z][0] != 0) here.
        int size = ht[z][0];
        int new_size = size + 1;
        ht[z] = realloc(ht[z],(new_size)*sizeof(int));  // Do not cast the return value.
        ht[z][size] = *x;
        ht[z][0] = new_size;  // Update your size 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code by making changes in the size thing and *z :

Comment: I have edited my code in the post kindly give it a look.